# shooting method to compute the interface shape

Tags: matlab, fluid-dynamics, numerics, ode, numerical-modelling

I am trying to use a shooting method to compute the shape of liquid-gas interface given by the following differential equation:

$$
\frac{d^2 \theta}{ds^2} = \frac{f(\theta)}{h(h + 3\lambda)}
$$

with $\frac{dh}{ds} = \sin\theta$. Here, $f(\theta) = -0.67(\sin\theta)^3/(\theta - \sin \theta \cos \theta)$, $\theta$ is an angle to be solved for, $s$ is the parameterization variable and $\lambda$ is a given constant. Boundary conditions are: $\theta|_{s = 0} = \theta_q$, $\theta|_{s=l} = \pi/2$, $h|_{s=0} = 0$ and $h|_{s=l} = d/2$, where $\theta_q$, $l$ and $d$ are given constants.

I have been told to use $\theta|_{s=l} = \pi/2$ as a control condition, i.e., to change the value of $\theta_q$ until $\theta|_{s=l}$ becomes $\pi/2$. Values of $h|_{s=0}$ and $h|_{s=l}$ are, however, fixed.

To solve this using a shooting method, I denote $Y = [\theta(s) \ u(s) \ h(s)]^T$, where $u = \frac{d\theta}{ds}$ and rewrite the differential equations as

$$
Y' = [u \ \ \frac{f(\theta)}{h(h + 3\lambda)} \ \ \sin \theta]^T
$$

I use initial guesses of $\theta = \theta_q$ and $u = 0$ at $s = 0$, solve the ODEs using $\verb|ode45|$ in MATLAB and iteratively update the value of $\theta_q$ using a bisection method. However, I am unable to get a converged solution and I don't understand where I am doing wrong - see code below for reference. As I am quite new to shooting method, I would appreciate any help in getting this work.

```
% initialize all parameters
% .....
theta_q_lower = 10*pi/180; % Lower bound of possible theta_q values
theta_q_upper = 68*pi/180; % Upper bound of possible theta_q values

% Shooting method loop
while abs(theta_q_upper - theta_q_lower) > tolerance
    % Guess of theta_q
    theta_q_guess = (theta_q_lower + theta_q_upper) / 2;
    
    % Solve the ODEs with the current guess for theta_q
    [s, Y] = ode45(@(s, Y) odefunc(s, Y, Ca, c, lambda, M), [0, hf], [theta_q_guess; 0; h0]);
    
    % Get the final value of theta from the ODE solution
    theta_l = Y(end, 1);
    
    % Adjust the guess based on the result
    if theta_l < theta_l_target % theta_q was too low
        theta_q_lower = theta_q_guess;
    else % theta_q was too high
        theta_q_upper = theta_q_guess;
    end
    iter = iter+1;
end

% Use the final guess for theta_q
theta_q_final = (theta_q_lower + theta_q_upper) / 2;

% Solve the ODEs one last time with the final theta_q
[s, Y] = ode45(@(s, Y) odefunc(s, Y, Ca, c, lambda, M), [0, hf], [theta_q_final; 0; h0]);

% Plot the results
plot(s, Y(:, 1)); % Plot theta(s)
hold on;
plot(s, Y(:, 3)); % Plot h(s)
legend('\theta(s)', 'h(s)');
xlabel('s');
ylabel('Value');
title('Shooting Method Solution');
hold off;

function dYds = odefunc(s, Y, Ca, c, lambda, M)
    % Unpack current values
    theta = Y(1);
    u = Y(2);
    h = Y(3);

    % Prevent division by zero by ensuring h is not too close to zero
    epsilon = 1e-7;
    h_safe = h + epsilon;    
    
    % Equations
    dtheta_ds = u;
    du_ds = F(theta, M) / (h_safe * (h_safe + c * lambda));
    dh_ds = sin(theta);
    
    dYds = [dtheta_ds; du_ds; dh_ds];
end

function Fval = F(theta, M)
    Fval = -0.67 * (sin(theta)^3) / (theta - sin(theta) * cos(theta));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your differential equation is nonlinear, it is not clear that using the bisection method to find the desired value for $\theta_q$ so that $\theta|_{s = l} = \pi/2$ is reasonable.

Let $f(\theta_q)$ be the value of $\theta|_{s = l}$ obtained after using $\theta|_{s = 0} = \theta_q$ as the initial condition for solving the differential equation, all other things being fixed. Let us also assume there actually does exist some value $\theta^*$ such that $f(\theta^*) = \pi/2$. If $f(\theta_q)$ is monotonic with respect to $\theta_q$, then your bisection approach should work given you do not have issues in your implementation. However, if $f(\theta_q)$ is not monotonic, things become trickier. In the worst case that $f(\theta_q)$ is nonconvex, then your approach may very well fail to find the desired $\theta^*$.

To help diagnose your situation, it may help to evaluate $f(\theta_q)$ for many values of $\theta_q$ in the range $[\pi/18, 68 \pi/ 180]$ and plot a figure to see what it looks like.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. plot of $f(\theta_q)$ is unfortunately monotonic.

Comment: @SthavishthaBhopalam given this is the case, then your binary search algorithm must be wrong because a correct implementation would return the desired answer. If you look at your algorithm, it assumes $f(\theta_q)$ is monotonically _increasing_. Is this a correct property of $f(\theta_q)$? If it is monotonically _decreasing_, then your algo will not return a correct result. Arguably, you should write your algorithm so it can handle both cases. Also, when you want the final guess for $\theta_q$, you should use a linear interpolation instead of just taking the average of the final bounds.